# Can I use JDT search engine while parsing a source from JDT AST

Tags: reference, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm using JDT AST to parse a given source. I want to find the references of a given object/variable when it triggers the relavant visitor when using AST.
E.g.:
Consider the following code:

```
public class SampleClass {
    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        SampleClass s =new SampleClass();
        // do some other work
        s.printMe();
    }
}
```

When I'm parsing the above code, when it comes to the variable declaration of "s", it will call the visitor method of "VariableDeclarationFragment" type. At that point I want to find out all the references of variable "s" before going to visit rest of the code lines. Is this possible? I thought of using JDT SearchEngine and call at that point to resolve the references separately. But wasn't successful. Can I do it by only using AST itself?

Please note that I'm using JDT AST in a stand-alone program and not as a Eclipse plugin project. I'm bit confused whether I can use the SearchEngine in that case as it couldnt resolve IJava* types for a given code unit (class,method etc.). 
Please share your expertise to sort out this.

Comment: If your problem is to identify language-accurate references to a particular variable, you need far more than just the AST. (Consider an instance of a variable s, and two scopes in which it is defined:  which scoped declaration does the instance refer to?).  You also need name and type resolution, which is way harder to get unless you have the guts of a compiler lying around.

Comment: Yes a valid point. Thanks for bringing it up. Just a thought: If I can find the references somehow, wouldn't it be possible to resolve the above problem using resolveBinding? since it gives you where a particular variable/method resides in the structure. However first I need to resolve my main problem of finding the references, at least in straight forward scenarios.

Comment: I'm not an expert in JDT.  I'll assume that resolveBinding actually does accurate name resolution.  But you realize that only works if you should have to have whole program (or at least enough to compile the file of interest), and not just your file ? (A missing file can mean a missing declaration or class, causing a name resolver to be unable to correctly resolve a choice).

Answer (score 1):

Using the search engine is overkill.  The search engine is meant for cross file searching.  And, without the workbench started (ie- without an Eclipse instance in the background) you cannot use the search engine.

It looks like you only want to find references to variables in the same file.  Your best bet here is to create a visitor that will visit the entire file and look for references to the variable.  Since these are variables and their scope doesn't escape the method they are declared in, you only need to visit that method.

Something like this:

```
class MyVariableVisitory extends ASTVisitor {
    public boolean visit(SimpleName node) {
        if (node.getIdentifier().equals(variableToLookFor)) {
            acceptMatch(node);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Since you are only looking for references to variables, you only need to look at `Name` ast nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Even though in this case it is limited to method scope,in some other cases it might required to search in class/package/project scope. Sorry I'm bit confused on your suggestion. Assume the same code I've given: In the existing visitor I'm using,the visit method of "VariableDeclarationFragment" type gets called when the parser comes to the line where "s" is declared.And I want to find out the references of "s" at that point it self before the existing parser moves forward from the current line.So what you suggest is to use another AST parser at that point? Please explain.

Comment: I had originally made the assumption that you knew which variable/field you were looking for.  But, if you don't know it yet, then you will need to do two passes over the AST.  The first to find the node you are interested in and the second to find references.  You will need to also parse and visit all other relevant files in the project, depending on the scope of the variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Initially, I also felt that I might have to go for such an approach. But then only I tried things like using the SearchEngine and was looking into the possibilities of using AST it self... etc. since having two AST parsing won't be a better approach in performance aspect. But seems to be that is the only option. May be I should check whether there are any other libraries available to get it done before get into the approach of using two ASTs.